# Power factor effects and causes

Tags: electrical-engineering

Why do power utilities impose power factor penalty when power factor goes low (less than 0.7)?

Why does the power factor get smaller when the load is much less than the max or rated power of transformer or generator?

Comment: What do you mean by a power factor penalty?

Answer (score 2):

Low power factor means that the load is shuttling energy repeatedly from and to the supply network. This is because the supply network is supplying energy to create magnetic / electric fields within the inductance and capacitance of the load over one half of the cycle, and that energy is being returned from the load to the supply network over the other half of the cycle.

Although it is true that there is no nett energy being used by this shuttling, the power supply company must still allow for a current component to transfer this energy. An ideal inductor will consume no energy long term, but it can still draw a heavy current needed to create / "deflate" its magnetic field cyclically.

Therefore, the current supply infrastructure needs to be heavier and able to cope with more current that it would need to were the power factor near to unity. This means higher costs to the supply company, and therefore ultimately to the consumer as those costs are passed on.

---

User CuriousOne makes the point:

> The excess current will also cause $I^2\,R$ losses in the transmission lines, transformers and generators, so there is a real loss of energy in the network.

Actually these excess losses are the *whole* picture: they indirectly account for the "infrastructure needs to be heavier" explanation I gave of the cost. My understanding of the economics (33 years ago in an EE course) is that the cost of the excess lost energy itself is a very small part of the cost. However, the excess losses are what set the power rating of equipment: you need thicker wires to reduce their resistance, and better heatsinking, transformer oil pumps and radiators and all the rest of it to make sure the equipment can dissipate excess losses without frying itself.

Comment: I would like to add one more point that in most utlities, a capacitor/inductor is added to  compensate the phase difference caused by the utility in order to save power.

Comment: @YashasSamaga That's done when it can be. But it wasn't always possible in the past, *e.g.* with variable loads on motors, changing their power factor. Nowadays, computer control of phasing through heavy current semiconductor thyristors allows even this problem to be overcome in industrial plants.

Comment: The excess current will also cause $I^2R$ losses in the transmission lines, transformers and generators, so there is a real loss of energy in the network.

Comment: @CuriousOne Excess losses, albeit indirectly, are ultimately the whole picture: see my update.

Comment: Exactly... this is the perfect example for imaginary numbers turning real at the speed of light. :-)

Comment: In now days capacitors are use along with detuned rectors to overthrow harmonics cause by non linear loads. Capacitors are controlled through various software which command different capacitors to charge and discharge anad control their time factor. We connects these capacitors through microprocessor programmed relay and then we attach detuned rectors if the THd factor is above the desired level unles we just only use sduty or hduty capacitors.